# I am trying to insert my score from textbox into database score and it didn't work

Tags: c#, sql

Here's my code:

```
con.Open();
String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_score (personality,style,poise,audience,total) VALUES ('" + 
               textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" +textBox3.Text + "','" + 
               textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "',)";
MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Voted");
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **never EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements - **ALWAYS** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You shouldn't build your query this way, but when you *have* to, *print* the resulting failing query (or look at it in the debugger) - you will probably spot the problem. And then fix it by using parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You should **ALWAYS** (no exceptions!) use **parameters** for your queries - it first of all avoids the #1 threat on the internet - SQL injection - and it also avoids messy issues with quotes around strings and so forth.

Try this code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_score (personality, style, poise, audience, total) " +
               "VALUES (@personality, @style, @poise, @audience, @total);";


using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
{
    // set the parameter values 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@personality", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@style", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@poise", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@audience", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox4.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox5.Text;

    // open connection, execute INSERT query, close connection
    con.Open();
    int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Voted");
```

Also, you should use the *most appropriate* datatype for your parameters - if a values is **numerical** (as I suspect for `@total`), then you should **use a numeric datatype** - don't just cast everything to a string - use the *correct* datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove comma(,) before end brace.

Your query must be

```
String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_score (personality,style,poise,audience,total) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";
```